# Force section and subsection numbers to appear in increasing order in book with un-numbered chapters

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm writing a thesis and need to use the `book` class. I'd like to number every section in the chapter as 1.1, 1.2 etc. but the numbers look very off. I found a few similar questions on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange) but none of them discusses a solution with the `book` class.

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Un-numbered chapter}
\subsection{Numbered subsection- should be 1.1}
\subsection{Another numbered subsection - should be 1.2}

\chapter*{Another Un-numbered chapter}
\subsection{Numbered subsection - should be 2.1}
\subsection{subsection - should be 2.2}
\subsubsection{sub-subsection - should be 2.2.1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If your aim is just to number your subsections inside chapters (what's implying you skip the section level and that's not a very good idea btw) then you could have a look at the `chngcntr` package.

Comment: I don't get this. Is there just one section per `\chapter*` ? The section counter shall not be reset?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer There are multiple sections, but I'd like to label each section with a decimal as 1.1 etc. instead of the default numbering that latex gives.

Comment: @linuxfan: Well, using unnumbered chapters will cause the chapter number to stick, but you removed the chapter already by redefinition of the `\thesection`. If you want resetting of section counters even for a unnumbered chapter, this needs more to do

Answer (score 2):

By not omitting `\section` and setting `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` the numbers are correct, provided that there should be no resetting.

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Un-numbered chapter}

\section{A numbered section}
\subsection{Numbered subsection- should be 1.1}
\subsection{Another numbered subsection - should be 1.2}


\chapter*{Another Un-numbered chapter}
\section{A numbered section}
\subsection{Numbered subsection - should be 2.1}
\subsection{subsection - should be 2.2}
\subsubsection{sub-subsection - should be 2.2.1}

\end{document}
```